# error in parsing the json url

Tags: jquery, json

while calling the url which contains the json data while parsing the page no error is shown and it doesn't return any data

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" " http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd ">
<html xmlns=" http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml ">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Request json test</title> 
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    //attach a jQuery live event to the button
    $('#getdata-button').live('click', function(){
        alert("get data"); 
        $.getJSON('http://evonixtech.com/ColegSCIT/getlistabout.php', function(data) {  
            alert(" data alert"+data); //uncomment this for debug
            //alert (data.item1+" "+data.item2+" "+data.item3); //further debug
            //$('#showdata').html("<p>item1="+data.item1+" item2="+data.item2+" item3="+data.item3+"</p>");
        });
    });
});
</script> 
</head>
<body>
<a href="#" id="getdata-button">Get JSON Data</a>
<div id="showdata"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

[Same origin policy:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)

> In computing, the same origin policy is an important security concept for a number of browser-side programming languages, such as JavaScript. The policy permits scripts running on pages originating from the same site to access each other's methods and properties with no specific restrictions, but prevents access to most methods and properties across pages on different sites